# JSP- How to pass parameters between quotes calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I have this snippet

```
            <c:forEach var="var" items="${selects.listOfVar}">
                <script>
                addIncFromSelect("param1","param2", "'" +${var} +"'");
                </script>
        </c:forEach>
```

What I would like to obtain is to call the "addIncFromSelect" function passing three parameters as string.
The problem I have right now with the code is that the third value is passed like

```
"'" + foo +"'"
```

instead of

```
"foo"
```

I also tried this:

```
<c:forEach var="var" items="${selects.listOfVar}">
    <script>
    addIncFromSelect("param1","param2", ${var});
    </script>
</c:forEach>
```

but in this way is passed

```
foo
```

and it's not working either

Comment: I would try `addIncFromSelect("param1","param2", "${var}");`

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer (and remove solved from title), accept your own answer instead see [tour] to learn more how SO works

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. This seem to work

```
<c:forEach var="varTemp" items="${selects.listOfVar}">
    <c:set var="var" value="'${varTemp}'"/>
    <script>
    addIncFromSelect("param1","param2", ${var});
    </script>
</c:forEach>
```